# EPS and GMC steering wheel vibrations

Tags: power-steering, steering, gmc, sierra, software

I recently went and got a recall done for my EPS on my 2015 GMC Sierra 1500. When i got it back from the deal I had vibrations in my steering wheel. This recall was a flash update on the software for the EPS. I am trying to figure out how this happened under there care of 30 mins. as they refuse to admit fault. I know for a fact it was not there before bringing them the truck as I just bought it from another deal and had it checked over 2 times by 2 different mechanics from a 3rd party place. Any ideas what could have gone wrong so i know how to handle the situation with the dealership that some how ruined my new truck?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!